# Test program for endianess dependency

Tags: gcc, qemu, endianness, powerpc

I am writing a C++ program, which hopefully shall produce exactly the same results regardless whether or not it is compiled/run on a little-endian or big-endian platform. However, I only have access to x86-64 computers (Linux/macOS/Windows). Though I have been very careful with things like `memcpy` from a raw buffer to an array of integers, etc. I still want to test the programs on a big-endian platform, say PPC64, to just be sure.

A few options I can think of,
1) Run a complete OS in QEMU. But it is extremely slow. The program takes 30 minutes to built on an 8-core Xeon. I can't even run the VM with reasonable smoothness, let alone build the program I need.
2) Use a cross-compiler and run QEMU in user mode. However, so far after trying a few guide, I fail to build a complete GCC-toolchain on CentOS 7.2.

Does anyone know a low overhead option or where to find pre-built cross compiler toolchains.

Comment: ELLCC, a clang based tool chain (http://ellcc.org), has pre-built binaries available. It only supports static linking at the moment, however.

Comment: @RichardPennington Thanks a lot. I tried it out and it works great.